# How to write a C++ swapPos function in a simple dex game?

Tags: c++

Consider the following definitions of two classes that have a composition relationship:

```
class Dex {
private:
    Position pos;
    int team;
public:
    Dex(int m, int n, int t);
    Position getPos() const;
    int getTeam() const;
    void swapPos(Dex& d);
   ~Dex();
};

class Position {
private: 
    int m;
    int n;
public:
    Position(int m, int n);
    void newPos(m, n);
    int getM() const;
    int getN() const;
}
;
```

A Dex is intended to represent a piece in a computer game that uses a hexagonal grid.
Positions on the grid are specified by a coordinate system that uses two integers (m and n) to
identify any cell in the grid, as follows:

[![enter image description here][1]][1]

From any cell, there are six directions: A, B, C, D, E and F. Note that the grid extends
indefinitely in all directions.

[![enter image description here][2]][2]

Movement in the A or D directions causes a change in the m coordinate. Movement in
the B or E directions causes a change in the n coordinate. Movement in the C or F
directions causes a simultaneous change in both the m and n coordinates.

NB: The rules of the game are not important. You are NOT required to write a program to play
the game. You must simply write a program to test the implementations of the Dex and
Position classes.

Firstly, implement the classes as follows:

• The Dex constructor should initialize the data members to the values provided as
parameters.

• getPos() should return a copy of the current position, and getTeam() the
team number.

• swapPos() swaps the position of the current instance with that of another
Dex instance.

• The member functions of Position are self-explanatory.

Note that the team data member is intended to allow a number of Dex instances to belong to
the same team, e.g. team number 1. How many Dexes there are in a team, and how many
teams there are, are part of the rules of the game and are not important for this exercise.
Similarly, the situations in which Dexes may be moved or have their positions swapped are not
important for this exercise. You must just make sure that the member functions do what is
specified above.

Next, write a short console app to test the Dex class. It should create at least four instances of
Dex and then test the member functions of this class using them.

Finally, change the Dex class so that the pos data member is a pointer to a Position. You
will also need to implement the Big Three (copy constructor, assignment operator, and
destructor) for the Dex class.  No changes to the Position class are
required.

My current implementation is as follow:

```
#ifndef DEX_H
#define DEX_H

#include "position.h"

class Dex
{
private:
    Position* pos;
    int team;
public:
    Dex(int m, int n, int t);
    Position getPos() const;
    int getTeam() const;
    void swapPos(Dex& d);
    Dex(const Dex & otherDex);
    Dex& operator=(const Dex& otherDex);
    ~Dex();
};

#endif // DEX_H
```

```
#ifndef POSITION_H
#define POSITION_H

class Position
{
private:
    int m;
    int n;
public:
    Position(int m, int n);
    void newPos(int m, int n);
    int getM() const;
    int getN() const;
};

#endif // POSITION_H
```

```
#include <stdexcept>
#include "dex.h"
#include "position.h"
#include <cmath>

Dex::Dex(int m, int n, int t)
    : pos(new Position(m, n)),
    team(t) {
}

Dex::Dex(const Dex& d)
    : pos(d.pos), team(d.team) {
}

Dex & Dex::operator=(const Dex & d)
{
    if (this != &d) {        /* operator=() should always do nothing in the case of self-assignment. */
        pos = d.pos;
        team = d.team;
    }
    return *this;
}

Dex::~Dex()
{
    delete pos;
}

Position Dex::getPos() const
{
    return *(pos);
}

int Dex::getTeam() const
{
    return team;
}

void Dex::swapPos(Dex& d)
{
    int tm = d.getPos().getM();
    int tn = d.getPos().getN();

    d.getPos().newPos(getPos().getM(), getPos().getN());
    getPos().newPos(tm, tn);

//    Position *temp;
//    temp = this->pos;
//    this->pos = d->pos;
//    d->pos = temp;
}
```

```
#include "position.h"

using namespace std;

Position::Position(int m, int n)
    : m{m}, n{n} {
}

void Position::newPos(int m, int n)
{
    this->m = m;
    this->n = n;
}

int Position::getM() const
{
    return m;
}

int Position::getN() const
{
    return n;
}
```

```
#include <QCoreApplication>
#include <iostream>
#include "dex.h"
#include <QList>

using namespace std;

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    QCoreApplication a(argc, argv);

    cout << "Welcome to Dex Game." << endl;
    cout << "testing..." << endl;

    Dex d1(2, 5, 1);
    Dex d2(d1);
    Dex d3(0, 0, 2);
    Dex d4(0, 0, 2);

    d1.swapPos(d3); // positions didn't change

    //show status of each dex
    cout << "Position of dex player 1: m" <<  d1.getPos().getM() << " n="
         << d1.getPos().getN() << " team=" << d1.getTeam() << endl;
    cout << "Position of dex player 2: m" <<  d2.getPos().getM() << " n="
         << d2.getPos().getN() << " team=" << d2.getTeam() << endl;
    cout << "Position of dex player 3: m" <<  d3.getPos().getM() << " n="
         << d3.getPos().getN() << " team=" << d3.getTeam() << endl;
    cout << "Position of dex player 4: m" <<  d4.getPos().getM() << " n="
         << d4.getPos().getN() << " team=" << d4.getTeam() << endl;

    return a.exec();
}
```

My stacks are as follow:
My swapPos function does not work.

Any guidance here will be greatly appreciated.
[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/FTs7D.png
[2]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/9prok.png

**UPDATE**
For the following C++ program I only need swapPos to work, which should swap the position (m and n) of one Dex instance with another Dex instance:

```
#ifndef DEX_H
#define DEX_H

#include "position.h"

class Dex
{
private:
    Position* pos;
public:
    Dex(int m, int n);
    Position getPos() const;
    bool move(char, int);
    void swapPos(Dex& d);
    Dex(const Dex & otherDex);
    Dex& operator=(const Dex& otherDex);
    ~Dex();
};

#endif // DEX_H
```

```
#ifndef POSITION_H
#define POSITION_H

class Position
{
private:
    int m;
    int n;
public:
    Position(int m, int n);
    void newPos(int m, int n);
    int getM() const;
    int getN() const;
};

#endif // POSITION_H
```

```
#include <stdexcept>
#include "dex.h"
#include "position.h"

Dex::Dex(int m, int n) {
    pos = new Position(m, n);
}

Dex::Dex(const Dex& d) {
    pos = new Position(d.getPos().getM(), d.getPos().getN());
}

Dex & Dex::operator=(const Dex & d)
{
    if (this != &d) {
        pos->newPos(d.getPos().getM(), d.getPos().getN());
    }

    return *this;
}

Dex::~Dex()
{
    delete pos;
}

Position Dex::getPos() const
{
    return *(pos);
}

bool Dex::move(char dn, int de)
{
    dn = toupper(dn);

    //test for invalid values
    if (dn != 'A' && dn != 'B' && dn != 'C' && dn != 'D' && dn != 'E' && dn != 'F' || de <= 0)
    {
        return false;
    }
    else
    {
        //horizontal movement
        if (dn == 'A')
        {
            int i = pos->getM() + de;
            pos->newPos(i, pos->getN());
        }
        if (dn == 'D')
        {
            int i = pos->getM() - de;
            pos->newPos(i, pos->getN());
        }

        //right diagonal movement
        if (dn == 'B')
        {
            int i = pos->getN() + de;
            pos->newPos(pos->getM(), i);
        }
        if (dn == 'E')
        {
            int i = pos->getN() - de;
            pos->newPos(pos->getM(), i);
        }

        //left diagonal movement
        if (dn == 'C')
        {
            int i = pos->getM() - de;
            int j = pos->getN() + de;
            pos->newPos(i, j);
        }
        if (dn == 'F')
        {
            int i = pos->getM() + de;
            int j = pos->getN() - de;
            pos->newPos(i , j);
        }

        return true;
    }
}

void Dex::swapPos(Dex& d)
{
    Position tp = d.getPos();
    d.getPos() = this->getPos();
    this->getPos() = tp;
}
```

```
#include "position.h"

using namespace std;

Position::Position(int m, int n)
    : m{m}, n{n} {
}

void Position::newPos(const int m, const int n)
{
    this->m = m;
    this->n = n;
}

int Position::getM() const
{
    return m;
}

int Position::getN() const
{
    return n;
}
```

```
#include <QCoreApplication>
#include <iostream>
#include "dex.h"

using namespace std;

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    QCoreApplication a(argc, argv);

    Dex d1(1, 2);
    Dex d2(d1);
    d2.move('B', 5);

    cout << "d1: m=" << d1.getPos().getM() << " n=" << d1.getPos().getN() << endl;
    cout << "d2: m=" << d2.getPos().getM() << " n=" << d2.getPos().getN() << endl;

    d1.swapPos(d2);

    cout << "d1: m=" << d1.getPos().getM() << " n=" << d1.getPos().getN() << endl;
    cout << "d2: m=" << d2.getPos().getM() << " n=" << d2.getPos().getN() << endl;

    return a.exec();
}
```

Is the fault in my constructors or in swapPos? What should I do differently? Thank you.

Comment: This looks a bit "homework dump"-y to me.  You'll be much more likely to get an answer if you can reduce this to a [mcve].  (e.g. just the `swapPos` function, if that is the one giving you trouble.)

Comment: Your copy ctor is implemented incorrectly - you dereference `pos` before initializing it. You must assign dynamically allocated object to it before as you do in default ctor. And class `Dex` is missing a destructor

Comment: Please ask one question per question, you asked too many. For example I cannot answer what is wrong with copy ctor as it would create incomplete answer.

Comment: Just help me fix the swapPos function. I'll figure the rest out myself.

Comment: Please remove everything from your question that is unrelated to the problem with the swapPos function. Provide a [mcve].

Comment: `pos` is a dangling pointer but the copy constructor dereferences it `*(this->pos) = otherDex.getPos();`. That's a big problem. Why do you use a pointer instead of an automatic variable?

Comment: A very annoying kind of teacher is those that have you do something in a particular way and that way doesn't solve any problems, but only causes them.

Comment: I updated my code; I only need assistance with swapPos. Thanks, @Slava, and your suggestions helped me so far.

Answer (score 0):

I got my Dex app to work. It's not the game itself but the functions that the game would call. Anyway, here is the complete code:

```
#ifndef DEX_H
#define DEX_H

#include "position.h"

class Dex
{
private:
    Position* pos;
    int team;
public:
    Dex(int m, int n, int t);
    Position getPos() const;
    int getTeam() const;
    bool move(char, int);
    bool lineOfSight(Dex *d) const;
    void swapPos(Dex& d);
    Dex(const Dex & otherDex);
    Dex& operator=(const Dex& otherDex);
    ~Dex();
};

#endif // DEX_H
```

```
#ifndef POSITION_H
#define POSITION_H

class Position
{
private:
    int m;
    int n;
public:
    Position(int m, int n);
    void newPos(int m, int n);
    int getM() const;
    int getN() const;
};

#endif // POSITION_H
```

```
#include <stdexcept>
#include "dex.h"
#include "position.h"
#include <cmath>

Dex::Dex(int m, int n, int t) {
    pos = new Position(m, n);
    team = t;
}

Dex::Dex(const Dex& d) {
    pos = new Position(d.getPos().getM(), d.getPos().getN());
    this->team = d.getTeam();
}

Dex & Dex::operator=(const Dex & d)
{
    if (this != &d) {
        pos->newPos(d.getPos().getM(), d.getPos().getN());
    }

    return *this;
}

Dex::~Dex()
{
    delete pos;
}

Position Dex::getPos() const
{
    return *(pos);
}

int Dex::getTeam() const
{
    return team;
}

bool Dex::move(char dn, int de)
{
    dn = toupper(dn);

    //test for invalid values
    if (dn != 'A' && dn != 'B' && dn != 'C' && dn != 'D' && dn != 'E' && dn != 'F' || de <= 0)
    {
        return false;
    }
    else
    {
        //horizontal movement
        if (dn == 'A')
        {
            int i = pos->getM() + de;
            pos->newPos(i, pos->getN());
        }
        if (dn == 'D')
        {
            int i = pos->getM() - de;
            pos->newPos(i, pos->getN());
        }

        //right diagonal movement
        if (dn == 'B')
        {
            int i = pos->getN() + de;
            pos->newPos(pos->getM(), i);
        }
        if (dn == 'E')
        {
            int i = pos->getN() - de;
            pos->newPos(pos->getM(), i);
        }

        //left diagonal movement
        if (dn == 'C')
        {
            int i = pos->getM() - de;
            int j = pos->getN() + de;
            pos->newPos(i, j);
        }
        if (dn == 'F')
        {
            int i = pos->getM() + de;
            int j = pos->getN() - de;
            pos->newPos(i , j);
        }

        return true;
    }
}

bool Dex::lineOfSight(Dex * d) const
{
    int tm = pos->getM();
    int tn = pos->getN();

    int dm = d->getPos().getM();
    int dn = d->getPos().getN();

    if (tm == dm)
    {
        return true;
    }
    else if (tn == dn)
    {
        return true;
    }
    else if (abs(tm - dm) == abs(tn - dn))
    {
        return true;
    }
    else
    {
        return false;
    }
}

void Dex::swapPos(Dex& d)
{
    Dex temp = d;
    temp = *this;
    *this = d;
    d = temp;
}
```

```
#include "position.h"

using namespace std;

Position::Position(int m, int n)
    : m{m}, n{n} {
}

void Position::newPos(int m, int n)
{
    this->m = m;
    this->n = n;
}

int Position::getM() const
{
    return m;
}

int Position::getN() const
{
    return n;
}
```

a simple main to test the implementation:

```
#include <QCoreApplication>
#include <iostream>
#include "dex.h"
#include <QList>

using namespace std;

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    QCoreApplication a(argc, argv);

    cout << "Welcome to Dex Game." << endl;
    cout << "testing..." << endl;

    Dex d1(2, 5, 1);
    Dex d2(d1);
    Dex d3(0, 0, 2);
    Dex d4(0, 0, 2);

    //show status of each dex
    cout << "Position of dex player 1: m" <<  d1.getPos().getM() << " n="
         << d1.getPos().getN() << " team=" << d1.getTeam() << endl;
    cout << "Position of dex player 2: m" <<  d2.getPos().getM() << " n="
         << d2.getPos().getN() << " team=" << d2.getTeam() << endl;
    cout << "Position of dex player 3: m" <<  d3.getPos().getM() << " n="
         << d3.getPos().getN() << " team=" << d3.getTeam() << endl;
    cout << "Position of dex player 4: m" <<  d4.getPos().getM() << " n="
         << d4.getPos().getN() << " team=" << d4.getTeam() << endl;

    //move players then check status and line of sight
    d1.move('A', 3);
    d2.move('C', 2);
    d3.move('F', 6);
    d4.move('E', 8);

    //show status of each dex
    cout << "Dex player 1 moved A3. Position of dex player 1: m" <<  d1.getPos().getM() << " n="
         << d1.getPos().getN() << " team=" << d1.getTeam() << endl;
    cout << "Dex player 2 moved C2. Position of dex player 2: m" <<  d2.getPos().getM() << " n="
         << d2.getPos().getN() << " team=" << d2.getTeam() << endl;
    cout << "Dex player 3 moved F6. Position of dex player 3: m" <<  d3.getPos().getM() << " n="
         << d3.getPos().getN() << " team=" << d3.getTeam() << endl;
    cout << "Dex player 4 moved E8. Position of dex player 4: m" <<  d4.getPos().getM() << " n="
         << d4.getPos().getN() << " team=" << d4.getTeam() << endl;

    //swap postions
    d1.swapPos(d3);
    cout << "The position of d1 was swapped with d3." << endl;

    //show status of each dex
    cout << "Position of dex player 1: m" <<  d1.getPos().getM() << " n="
         << d1.getPos().getN() << " team=" << d1.getTeam() << endl;
    cout << "Position of dex player 3: m" <<  d3.getPos().getM() << " n="
         << d3.getPos().getN() << " team=" << d3.getTeam() << endl;

    //line of sight
    if (d1.lineOfSight(&d2))
    {
        cout << "Dex player 1 is in line of sight with dex player 2." << endl;
    }
    else
    {
        cout << "Dex player 1 is not in line of sight with dex player 2." << endl;
    }
    if (d1.lineOfSight(&d3))
    {
        cout << "Dex player 1 is in line of sight with dex player 3." << endl;
    }
    else
    {
        cout << "Dex player 1 is not in line of sight with dex player 3." << endl;
    }
    if (d1.lineOfSight(&d4))
    {
        cout << "Dex player 1 is in line of sight with dex player 4." << endl;
    }
    else
    {
        cout << "Dex player 1 is not in line of sight with dex player 4." << endl;
    }
    if (d2.lineOfSight(&d3))
    {
        cout << "Dex player 2 is in line of sight with dex player 3." << endl;
    }
    else
    {
        cout << "Dex player 3 is not in line of sight with dex player 3." << endl;
    }
    if (d2.lineOfSight(&d4))
    {
        cout << "Dex player 2 is in line of sight with dex player 4." << endl;
    }
    else
    {
        cout << "Dex player 2 is not in line of sight with dex player 4." << endl;
    }

    return a.exec();
}
```